# File systems appropriate for synchronising to flash memory

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, rsync, journaling

I want to rsync from an ext4 drive to flash memory. Which filesystem would allow funky file and folder names as well as writing non-regular files? (In my case, when I sync to fat32 rsync skips a bunch of files from git, for instance even " ~/.../Library/Aliases/node.js ".)

The reason I am avoiding ext4 is that its journalism system's excessive writing shortens the life of the flash memory.

All in all, do non journaling systems supporting ext4 naming conventions exist? And what does rsync's skipping "non-regular" files has anything to do with this if at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do non journaling systems supporting ext4 naming conventions exist?

Simply tell ext4 not to use a journal:

```
tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdxN
```

If you're going to create a filesystem anew, disable the option from the very beginning:

```
mke2fs [other options] -O ^has_journal /dev/sdxN
```

See `man 8 tune2fs` and `man 8 mke2fs` for details.

Notes:

- I'm not sure if you can (or should) run the above `tune2fs` command on a mounted filesystem. I would `umount` it first just in case.
- You may have used `mkfs.ext4` instead of `mke2fs` to create ext4 filesystems. These are two names for exactly the same command.